# Computing $\lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}(x^x)^x$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to determine $\lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}(x^x)^x$

My idea: By definition, it is $(x^x)^x=(e^{x\log x})^x=e^{x^2\log x}$.

It has already been proved that, for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R_+^*}$, $\lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}x^\alpha \log x = 0$. Since the exponential function is continuous, we have

$\lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}(x^x)^x= \lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}e^{x^2\log x}=e^0=1$

Answer (score 3):

That is indeed one of the simple approaches to the problem. (Btw, you meant $\alpha > 0$)

You can apply continuity in an even simpler way: the limit is already of the form $1^0$.