# Computing $\lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}x^{(x^x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f$ be a positive function with $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = \alpha$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R_+^*}$  and $\lim_{x \to x_0} g(x)=\beta$ with $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta \neq 0$.

Since the exponential function is continuous, we have $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)^{g(x)}= \lim_{x \to x_0} \exp \left( g(x) \log f(x) \right)= \exp \beta \log \alpha  =\alpha^\beta$.

Since it has already been shown, that $\lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}x^x = 1
\Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}x^{(x^x)} = \lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}x^{\lim\limits_{x \downarrow 0}(x^x)}=0^1=0$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. It's correct.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/626078/173147