# Can we calculate $\lim_{x \to 0+}{x^{(x^x)}}$ without using extended real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Can we calculate $\lim_{x \to 0+}{x^{(x^x)}}$ without using [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line)?

Today I tried to calculate $$\lim_{x \to 0+}{x^{(x^x)}},$$

which can be written as$$\lim_{x \to 0+}{e^{(x^x \log x)}},$$

and since $$x^x \log x \to -\infty\;\;\text{ as }\;\;x\to 0+,$$
the limit becomes $$e^{-\infty}=0.$$ However, I haven't learned the extended real number system. That is, I can't treat $-\infty$ as a number. Therefore, I can't calculate $\lim_{x \to 0+}{x^{(x^x)}}$ using this approach.

I have read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626136/computing-lim-limits-x-downarrow-0xxx), but I found that there seems to be an error: the condition is $\alpha \in \mathbb{R_+^*}$, but $0 \not\in \mathbb{R_+^*}$.

Are there other methods to calculate the limit without using extended real numbers?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use the definition of your $\lim$ and note that $e^x$ is continuous.

Comment: I think calculating that *using extended real numbers* would be more difficult than the usual ways to determine that run-of-the-mill limit.

Comment: Extended real numbers are used for convenience (mainly to write some statements in concise manner and save effort of typing) and not to fulfill a genuine mathematical need (like being indispensable for proving some theorem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why
you think that 
the extended reals are needed.

Once you have
$x^x \log x \to -\infty\;\;\text{ as }\;\;x\to 0+,
$
just taking the exponential 
works fine.

You are not taking
$e^{-\infty}$,
you are doing
$\lim_{x \to 0^+}e^{f(x)}$
where
$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)
=-\infty$.

Comment: I see. Although my textbook (by Apostol) doesn't have a theorem for me to do $\lim_{x \to 0^+}e^{f(x)}$ where $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x)=-\infty$, I think I can prove the result using the definition of limit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that for all $x\gt0$, $x\log(x)\ge-\frac1e$. Therefore, $x^x\ge e^{-1/e}$. Thus, for $0\lt x\le1$,
$$
0\lt x^{x^x}\le x^{e^{-1/e}}
$$
Now, the Squeeze Theorem says that
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x^{x^x}=0
$$
No extended reals are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $e^{-\infty}$ is undefined as a real number.

However, we always use this to interpret the limit of exponent is $-\infty$. $-\infty\notin\mathbb R$.

However, we can show that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^x=0$ (It would be easy using definition of limit of function and limit of sequence plus some knowledge about natural logarithm $\ln$).

To conclude, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{x^x}=0$.

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo in last limit. Is it right now?

Comment: Yes. I'm still missing some noticing of the continuity of $e^x$